# differentiating identical select names

Tags: php, javascript, html

how can I differentiate the 'select name' of 'f1' and 'f2' currently both named 'subcat' while still having only 1 subcat variable? this code works accurately only if cat value=2, if cat value=1 then subcat value always =0

```
<?php    
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$subcat = $_POST['subcat'];
?>
<form action='submitsite.php' method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>category(optional)</td>
            <td>
                <select name='cat' id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
                    <option value = "0">Select</option>
                    <option value = "1">music </option>
                    <option value = "2">film </option>
                </select> 
                <div id = "f1" style="display:none">
                    <select name='subcat' id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
                        <option value = "0">Select</option>
                        <option value = "3">pop</option>
                        <option value = "4">rock </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id = "f2" style="display:none">
                    <select name='subcat' id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
                        <option value = "0">Select</option>
                        <option value = "5">comedy</option>
                        <option value = "6">drama</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    function showForm(){
        var selopt = document.getElementById("opts").value;

        if (selopt == 1) {
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display="none";
        }
        if (selopt == 2) {
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("f1").style.display="none";
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I am not even giving that code a second look before it's properly indented.

Comment: There is a whole lot wrong with your code.

Comment: @Codemonkey I did my best, but that is NOT valid HTML.

Comment: @Matt i am rewriting his code now as valid html in jsfiddle.

Comment: @sam It looks like halfway through, OP stopped using `table`s and started using `div`s, except he forgot to remove the `table`s entirely.

Comment: @user1559811 I want to check what your looking for. When the user chooses one of the options in the first select you want to show them one of the two next ones?

Comment: @Sam OP is going about this all wrong, I think.

Comment: @Matt Check out my answer, do you think that's what he means?

Comment: @Sam I also edited my answer. Take a look. I tried not to use jQuery because I have a feeling OP won't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have altered a lot of your code to make it valid html and also work as i "think" you want it as your question did not make it very clear.

Here is a list of amends I had to make:

1. Changed ID's to make it clear what they are for.
2. Removed duplicate ID's.
3. Closed off your table properly.
4. Completely changed your JavaScript to show and hide certain select's
5. Many more things that I have forgotten.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9Y4a/2/).

Fixed html:

```
<form action='submitsite.php' method='POST'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>category(optional)</td>
      <td>
         <select name="cat" id="selectType">
           <option value="0">Select</option>
           <option value="1">music</option>
           <option value="2">film</option>
         </select> 

         <div id="f1" style="display:none">
           <select name='music' id="selectMusic">
             <option value="0">Select</option>
             <option value="3">pop</option>
             <option value="4">rock</option>
           </select>
         </div>

         <div id="f2" style="display:none">
           <select name="type" id="selectFilm">
             <option value="0">Select</option>
             <option value="5">comedy</option>
             <option value="6">drama</option>
           </select>
         </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>      
 </form>
```

Fixed JavaScript:

```
$("#selectType").change(function() {

  var selected = $(this).val();
  $("#f1, #f2").hide();

  switch (selected) {
    case "1":
      $("#f1").show();
      break;

    case "2":
      $("#f2").show();
      break;           
  }            
});​​
```

Comment: I think jQuery is a little advanced for OP, but this will help.

Comment: thank you, I am having a little trouble integrating the javascript, but I will keep at I'm sure it will come good, thanks for the code :)

Comment: @user1559811 No problem, let me know in the comments if you have any problems with it :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `[]` to the name. The selects will then be interpreted as an array when submitted.

```
<select name="subcat[]">...</select>
```

With PHP it can be accessed (if `POST`ed) like this:

```
<?php

    $subCatArr = $_POST['subcat'];

    $firstIndex = $subCatArr[0];
    $secondIndex = $subCatArr[1];
```

Oh yeah, and reusing IDs in HTML is not valid. They must be ***unique***.

**UPDATE** After better understanding OP's intent:

If I understand the intent of this spaghetti code (that's a term of endearment, OP), the user may select one category and one subcategory, which is based on the category that he/she selected. Then the user submits the form and that selection is recorded in the database.

First of all, let's get rid of the use of `table` elements, because they're unnecessary. Secondly, you only need one `select` for the subcategory.

```
<form action='submitsite.php' method='POST'>
    <label>category(optional)</label>
    <select name='cat' id = "opts" onchange = "showForm()">
        <option value = "0">Select</option>
        <option value = "1">music </option>
        <option value = "2">film </option>
    </select> 
    <div id="subcatDiv" style="display:none;">
        <select name='subcat' id='opts'></select>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

We can leave it blank, since it's not being displayed anyway.

Now, when the user makes a change, we'll either display the appropriate subcategories, or we'll just hide the `div` again:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function showForm(){
        var selopt = document.getElementById("opts");
        var seloptVal = selOpt.value;
        var subcatDiv = document.getElementById("subcatDiv");

        var options = "";
        switch(seloptVal * 1) {
            case 1:
                options = "<option value='0'>Select</option>" + 
                    "<option value='3'>pop</option>" + 
                    "<option value='4'>rock</option>";
                break;
            case 2:
                options = "<option value='0'>Select</option>" + 
                    "<option value='5'>comedy</option>" + 
                    "<option value='6'>drama</option>";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (options == "") {
            subcatDiv.style.display = "none";
            selopt.innerHTML = options;
        } else {
            selopt.innerHTML = options;
            subcatDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now you only have to deal with one `select` for the subcategory.

Comment: Please add that reusing ids in HTML is a deadly sin and you will have my vote.

Comment: ok, I'm getting an Undefined offset: 0 notice, also when inserting into mysql do I call the variable $subCatArr ?

Comment: @user1559811 Well, first make sure that `$_POST['subcat']` has a value. Do this with `var_dump($_POST['subcat']);`

Comment: @user1559811 The purpose of this is to allow the user to select a subcategory based on the category he/she selected, then submit the form. Am I correct?

Comment: @user1559811 You don't need two different `select` elements for the subcategory in order to do that. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: @user1559811 The javascript may not be 100% correct, but hopefully you can get the gist of what I'm doing and fix any bugs.  I haven't used straight javascript in a long time since jQuery is much easier to work with.

Comment: I apprecite the code, still working at it but you have helped a lot Thank you.   :)

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms[0].subcat` will be an array.

`document.forms[0].subcat[0]` will be the first instance, etc.

p.s. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('f2').getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
```

You are violating HTML standards by reusing IDs, by the way.